# Error when MFPCreateMediaPlayer calls

Tags: windows, com, media-player, ms-media-foundation

I'm using media foundation player for rendering video in my app window.

On my host machine everything is ok, but when i run my app automaticaly (on the remote build server), MFPCreateMediaPlayer call returns with 0x80040154 error code ("Class not registered").

How it is possible to register class, how can i figure, which class needs to be registered, why this issue appears only on the remotes? Any usefull links are acceptable.

Tnx!

ANSWER: i find out, that problem was caused by disabled Desktop Experience service. As i enable this service and restart build server (running on Windows Server 2008 R2), MFPCreateMediaPlayer call return success code and video starts to play. Hope it can helps someone.

Comment: It makes sense to post answer as answer (as opposed to question edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER: i found out, that problem was caused by disabled Desktop Experience service. As i enable this service and restart build server (running on Windows Server 2008 R2), MFPCreateMediaPlayer call return success code and video starts to play. Hope it can helps someone.